# Create commandButton in JSF using loop?

Tags: java, jsf, loops

for an example in an array there is

Edit --> #{testBean.edit}
Delete --> #{testBean.delete}
Copy --> #{testBean.copy}

is it possible to create commandbutton using loop or something

```
for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++)<br>
{
print '<h:commandbutton value="#{testBean.array.name}" action="#{testBean.array.action}" />'
}
```

so the output shld be like

```
<h:commandbutton value="Edit" action="#{testBean.edit}" />
<h:commandbutton value="Delete" action="#{testBean.delete}" />
<h:commandbutton value="Copy" action="#{testBean.copy}" />
```

Comment: should be possible to call action from other beans too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only possible if you change the collection (map?) to look something like

```
Edit --> edit
Delete --> delete
Copy --> copy
```

E.g.

```
Map<String, String> buttons = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
buttons.put("Edit", "edit");
buttons.put("Delete", "delete");
buttons.put("Copy", "copy");
```

You can then loop over it as follows:

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.buttons}" var="button">
    <h:commandButton value="#{button.key}" action="#{bean[button.value]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

As an alternative, you can create the components programmatically from in the bean side.

Comment: is it possible to call action from other class beans too?

Comment: You have to put it in a separate property and you have to know the bean scope as well. Then you can use something like `#{requestScope[managedBeanName][actionMethodName]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried Facelet repeat Tag 
http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/repeat.shtml